# Check if the file contains the name shell script

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a text file, and I am trying to check if the file contains the name given in argument.

I'm done with reading in the name and it echos the name.

I'm want the code to echo all the names from the text if the name in the argument is not in the file

```
while read -r fname lname;
do
 x="$fname $lname"
 if [ "$x" != "$1" ]
 then
   echo $x
 fi
done < names.txt
```

Comment: grep is your friend here, I think.

Comment: `x="$fname $lname"` ?? Try using the shell's debug/trace feature and add `set -vx` as 2nd line of the script. This will show you each line of code as it is in your script and below that it will show you what values have been substituted for the variables. Note that the `-v` part also outputs any loops, as a trace, and then processes inside the loop as mentioned. But yes, do you know about `grep srchTarget file` ? Good luck.

Comment: If you want to search for all names in the file NOT equal to the name passed as a parameter, use grep -v for an inverse match

Answer (score -1):

This should work,

`read -r fname lname x="$fname $lname" if [x != $(grep $(x) filename)] then echo $x fi`

Update: Errors have been edited.